# Rename filename python

Tags: python

I'm trying to rename filenames stored in a directory using python. Here is my script :

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("photos")

for file in path.glob("*.jpg"):
    newname = file.replace('Photo/siteTHQSE/','')
    file.rename(file, newname)
```

However when I execute it I'm told that the replace method is requires 2 arguments but 3 were given:

```
TypeError: replace() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Should you be using rename() instead of replace?  Are you trying to replace the text inside of a filename?

Comment: I'm trying to change the name of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `.replace()` incorrectly.  `file` is not a string; it's a `PosixPath` object.  Its `replace` method actually renames the file, and only takes one argument.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want the replace on the **name** of the file instead of the file itself.

Something like: `newname = file.name.replace('Photo/siteTHQSE/','')`

Comment: Yes, this what I want to do actually

Comment: Great, if it worked for you, you can mark this as the correct answer. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Using bashcommands

```html
bashCommand = "cp oldfile newfile"
os.system(bashCommand)
```